# Differ between elements when XML reused by including?

Tags: android, xml, onclicklistener

I got a LinearLayout where I add the Layout of a seperate XML.
In that seperate XML I added a OnClickListener on that Layout.
Now when the Layout is clicked, a new View is added where the User has to type some information.
When ready the additional View is closed and the data has to be put in the right element.
But it does always put it in the first of them.
How can I tell the Listener in which one it has to put it?

Thanks in advance.

editElement is called if one of those multiple included elements is clicked.
The saveEdit when the finish button of the editor is clicked.

```
public void editElement(View view) {
    FrameLayout base = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.base);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout editor = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.element_editor, null);
    editorID = editor.getId();
    base.addView(editor);

    currEdit = view.getId();

    TextView day = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.day);

    TextView day_editor = (TextView) editor.findViewById(R.id.day_editor);

    day_editor.setText(day.getText());
}

public void saveEdit(View view) {
    FrameLayout base = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.base);

    GridLayout parent = (GridLayout) view.getParent();

    LinearLayout element = (LinearLayout) findViewById(currEdit);

    TextView dur_act = (TextView) element.findViewById(R.id.duration_activity);
    EditText act = (EditText) parent.findViewById(R.id.de_activity);
    EditText dur = (EditText) parent.findViewById(R.id.de_duration);
    dur_act.setText(dur.getText()+(!dur.getText().equals("")?"":" min ")+act.getText());

    TextView comment = (TextView) diaryelement.findViewById(R.id.comment);
    EditText comm = (EditText) parent.findViewById(R.id.e_comment);
    comment.setText(comm.getText());

    base.removeView(findViewById(editorID));
}
```

Comment: you should pass the view of that element which is going to have data but i can help more if you post your code and layout.

Comment: added some code

Comment: have you tried multitouch approach.

Comment: no i'm new on android. what's that?